# Twitter bootstrap navbar tab "hide" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a twitter-bootstrap nav bar combined with tabs to load in forms via ajax (I'm using Django to serve the forms)

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#form1" data-toggle="tab">Form1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#form2" data-toggle="tab">Form2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#form3" data-toggle="tab">Form3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="form1" data-src="{% url form1 %}"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="form2" data-src="{% url form2 %}"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="form3" data-src="{% url form3 %}"></div>
</div>
```

This couples with the jquery:

```
$('#tabs').bind('show', function(element) {
  paneID = $(element.target).attr('href');
  src = $(paneID).attr('data-src');
  $(paneID).load(src);
});
```

Firstly, part of me wonders whether this might be a bad idea. I can't think of a reason why but if someone could point out to me whether this method has any drawbacks I would appreciate it.

Secondly, When I navigate away from a tab, I'd like to trigger the "onunload" event for that tabs content. But I can't seem to find a way to "unload" the data from a tab when it is navigated away from.

```
$('#tabs').bind('hide', function(element) {
  doStuff();
});
```

is not valid apparently. Any help/guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap tab fires an event when the tab is shown.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs

Taken from bootstrap:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
```

You can use the relatedTarget. That is the tab that just "unloaded".